# SMB transfer on one computer broken, but another computer can handle it, and I can access the other computer

Tags: network-shares, smb

I have a local network, and I have made an SMB file share called "Share" on my computer. It used to work on another computer, one that is very strong in performance.

Recently I noticed an issue. When trying to access that file share on the strong computer, it would say "You do not have permission to access \\SEAN\Share. Contact your network administrator to request access." (SEAN is my hostname.)

This led to a problem for me. I closed the SMB share and opened it again, same thing happened. I turned off password protected sharing, still the same. I did all I can and the same results were given.

Meanwhile, another computer (that being a slow machine) could access it fine, especially with credentials. My machine (the host) and the aforementioned computer were both on the 5G network, but the slow machine was on the 2.4G network.

I also have set up an SMB share on the powerful PC titled "Share", and especially with credentials, it works fine for my PC (the host).

It's worth noting that these PCs are running Windows 10 Home. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is one or both of the systems trying to use SMBv1?  That is gone now unless you tried to put it back. Are you trying to use Home Group?  That is gone as well.  Are both computers at the same Update level?

Comment: @John The file shares were made using File Explorer's share option. I'm not sure what SMB version they use, although I know Homegroups were removed. My computer and the "powerful computer" both use the latest version of Windows 10 Home, but the slow machine wasn't at the latest version.

Comment: Try updating the machine with the older version. I use Sync Back Pro and traditional file sharing on my computers and it works well